# Google App Engine - php friendly urls and $_GET parameters

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cloud

So, in a "regular" web server one can use mod_rewrite and create something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ ?menu=$1&action=$2&title=$3
</IfModule>
```

I tried several different ways to do something in app.yaml, but no success so far. The one that seemed closer is this one:

```
handler:
 - url: /([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$
   script: index.php?menu=\1&action=\2&title=\3
```

However, it gave an error saying that I was trying to require a filename called "index.php?<all_the_url_parameters_here>", which couldn't be found, obviously.

I really need some advice.

Comment: I already deployed some basic testing system: http://www.learn-prog.appspot.com/. The short urls were implemented in pure php, not with the help of app.yaml config file.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes you can...

Comment: @Lipis I did not know that! Anyway, "The PHP runtime is available as an experimental Preview feature. Please be aware that the APIs and service may change before the service becomes Generally Available."

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I'm not a fan of PHP either.. but yes it's there and that was more or less the message for all currently supported languages in the beginning..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do re-writes like this in php code - app.yaml cannot do it for you.

Check out the section on "Clean URLs" in Jimmys blog [here](http://blog.boombatower.com/drupal-google-app-engine) for an example to work from.

Comment: Or if you prefer https://github.com/boombatower/drupal-appengine/blob/7.x-appengine/wrapper.php

Comment: Accepting the answer because it clearly states that it is not possible to do rewrites with app.yaml.